# iPhone to other device using WIFI

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, rfid

I would like to build an iPhone app that, depending on the presence of a certain wireless device, verified by MAC address, would record the phone's position.

I've investigated the possibility of using Bluetooth for the wireless device but I don't want to go through the pain of the MFI program.

I'm falling back to using WIFI for this.  The iPhone app would check the presence of the hardware regularly by establishing a TCP/IP connection and checking the MAC address of the device.

I read a bit about WIFI RFID tags which at regular time intervals are publishing their MAC address. Would an iPhone app be able to programmatically connect to such a device, by using an adhoc connection?

If the WIFI RFID is not an option and I end up building such a device that can be connected to through WIFI, the question is the same, can an iPhone app establish a peer-to-peer connection to such a device?

Comment: did you found any solution over this?